# Gorm AutoMigrate Possibly Not Working As I Think it Should?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have been using Gorm for a year and it has been working pretty good. However, I am trying to refactor my db schema and for some reason Gorm is not migrating as expected.  My application is a multi-tenant application so I have a concept of a client id, which is using a POSTGRES Db ("PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 10.0.1 , 64-bit"). The issue is that I foolishly name some of my structs/columns with a prefix of our company name, lets call the company COM. So, for example, my client struct WAS COMClient, and now it is just client (I have removed some data for simplicity)

type Client struct {
ID String
Name           string
Address        string
}

I then had a Base struct of the following
type BaseClient struct {
ID string
ClientID string `gorm:"type:uuid"`
Client   *Client
}

Again, the base struct has fields of COMClientID and COMClient. This base client struct would be used in all of my other structs, where I needed to have a foreign key back to my client table. For example,
my user struct would be:

type ClientUser struct {
**BaseClient**
FirstName    string
LastName     string
Email        string `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
Password     string
}

In a nutshell, I am refactoring COMClient => Client. I then migrate all my structs when the application starts like the following:

db.AutoMigrate(&Client{})
db.AutoMigrate(&ClientUser{})
etc....

The issue is that a column client_id is not created in every table which has a foreign key to the clients table. Those tables all have foreign keys to the old client table 'com_clients'.

However, if I run my whole migration on a new db, everything gets created as it should be...

I have been wracking my head for hours, on why SOME tables have the column created and some do not.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a little embarrassing, but I figured out my issue...I am only posting this, in case someone else makes the same mistake.

If your db is not migrating as expected, run the AutoMigrate with Debug(), so db.Debug().AutoMigrate(tables...).

When I decided to use Gorm, I made the decision to use their conventions, however, if you make a typo (like I did), things won't work.

**Should Be - Very Simple**
ClientID string
Client  *Client

**What I Did**
ClientID string
Clent *Client

I forgot the 'i' in client.

Comment: thank for for your own reply, I was searching for my problem and your advice to enable Debug saved me hours :)